# Yii 1 oauth 2 server

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii1.x

Are there some oauth2 server libraries in Yii 1 just like https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel on laravel 4 or 5? Been searching for one. Couldn't find one

Thanks!